# How to connect Sonoff Minir2 to this wiring?

Tags: switches

My ultimate goal here is to connect a Sonoff Minir2 to the existing switch in my wall. This video allowed me to identify the switch (Busch-Jaeger) (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rV6tC_0wF50) and showed which cables are live and neutrals.

Theoretically that should be enough information to connect the Sonoff Minir2, I assume.

However, in the video are only two cables. One live and one neutral. Now the switch in my wall has two live cables and two neutral cables though.

Can I just connect them to the Sonoff Minir2 in any order? As long as I don't switch live and neutral though, of course!

Then connect an extra two cables from the Sonoff Minir2 to the switch using the S1 and S2.

[image: Sonoff Minir2]

[image: Busch-Jaeger Switch]

Comment: You need to provide more details (schematic) about the existing switch circuit. But judging from the picture it's a "type 6" switch, which indicates SPDT in west europe, with one of the poles unused (thus, used as a SPST). Which means you'd need to run an additional neutral wire because that sonoff thing needs it's own power supply.

Comment: @Unimportant, I don't have any. I am the tenant in a flat I don't own. It is in Europe/Germany. The switch is a bathroom switch which also switches on a bathroom fan. Didn't know about the different switch types, thanks. Will do some research.